# how to select in xpath all nodes except the nodes under a table node that contains a li node?

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

I have a many tables, and I want to select all the nodes from these tables, except those tables that contains at least a li node.

Example:

```
<table>
<tr><td>all these nodes should match</td></tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr><td><ul><li>all these nodes including table should NOT match</li></ul></td></tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr><td><div>all these nodes should match</div></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### XPATH:

```
/root/table[not(descendant::li)]
```

### XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>all these nodes should match</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>all these nodes including table should NOT match</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>all these nodes should match</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
//table[count(.//li) eq 0]
```